# x86 ASM: useless conditional jump?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I am looking at the following piece of x86 assembly code (Intel syntax):

```x86asm
movzx   eax, al
and     eax, 3
cmp     eax, 3
ja      loc_6BE9A0
```

In my understanding, this should equal something like this in C:

```c
eax &= 0xFF;
eax &= 3;
if (eax > 3)
   loc_6BE9A0();
```

This does not seem to make much sense since this condition will never be true (because `eax` will never be greater than 3 if it got and-ed with 3 before). Am I missing something here or is this really just an unnecessary condition?

And also: the `movzx eax, al` should not be necessary either if it gets and-ed with 3 right after that, is it?

I am asking this because I am not so familiar with assembly language and so I am not entirely sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Where did you get that asm / machine-code from?  A debug build from a C compiler?

Comment: Nope, a release build of a game :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct: the `movzx` is redundant given the following `and`.  It might have been produced by a non-optimizing compiler.

And yes, if this code executes straight through then the `ja` jump will never be taken.  However, the `cmp/ja` may not be completely useless if there is code somewhere else that jumps straight to the `cmp` (or even to the `ja`).

Comment: It's *possible* the movzx is there to avoid partial-register stalls on Intel P6-family, if earlier code only wrote AL and something actually needs to read the full register later (so this code couldn't have just used `and al, 3`).  But given the rest of the code-gen, it's probably just a silly compiler, possible MSVC in debug mode.  (GCC -O0 doesn't optimize between statements, but it's not usually this dumb within a single statement.  Neither is clang.  I'm assuming single-statement otherwise the var would spill/reload to the stack in a debug build.)

Comment: I was wrong, `gcc -O0` *will* emit that sequence when `al` comes from a function return value of `unsigned char`, but not when derefing an `unsigned char*`.

Answer (score 2):

This is redundant, and not something you'd see in optimized asm.

Even if the `cmp/ja` was a possible jump target from somewhere else, existing optimizing compilers like GCC, clang, MSVC, and ICC would (I'm pretty sure) do a `jmp` or different code layout instead of letting execution fall into a conditional branch that would always be false.  The optimizer would know there doesn't need to be a conditional branch along this path of execution, so would make sure it didn't encounter one.  (Even if that cost an additional `jmp`.)

That's probably a good choice, even in the hypothetical case where some code-size saving was possible this way, because you don't want to pollute / dilute branch-prediction history with unnecessary conditional branches, and the branch could mispredict as taken.

---

**But in debug mode, some compilers are more able to switch off their brains than others for optimizations within a single statement or expression**.  ([Across statements they'd always spill/reload vars to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point), unless you used `register int foo;`)

**I was able to trick clang `-O0` and MSVC into emitting that exact sequence of instructions**.  And also something like that but worse from GCC.
(Surprising because `gcc -O0` still does some optimizations inside a single expression like using a multiplicative inverse for `x /= 10;`, and dead code removal for `if(false)`.  vs. MSVC actually putting a 0 in a register and testing that it's 0.)

```
void dummy();
unsigned char set_al();
int foo(void) {
    if ((set_al() & 3) <= 3U)
        dummy();
    return 0;
}
```

clang12.0 for x86-64 Linux (**[on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrWVX0AGTy1MAOWcARpjEXLwADqhChOa0do4uyhFRZnRePv5OQSE8RpgmKbQMBMzEBHHOrpy5%2BTFFJQRpfoHBykLFpeUJVW31jRlZXACURqgOxMgcUgBuqHjoANTozk4AnhCDmgDM%2BjIAgg60UcA%2BC8gIJfMiBAD6bOtbO7veBPM0qBAzc4PzmgDsj/NAfM8FR5lArrdWOsftoAGzzTbfLY2LYAEQRAg2eyBOMWyzWG22mmxQOImAIY1o8xkD2Juz%2BqLpdOe8wCJQgByOJ3mZwuACowkj/nScSCwRABTD4YifpsUZt0ZtMSLcYClk5VvciSTAWSKcQqTTtfTfoy9lJhqxpABWeSuWTyVDSFF6AyXUbjTAwzaceQEaRyQbDADWIE2mwAdOHozHY7CVNJuHaA47pPIhCAZKR/Q7hnBYEg0E4wnh2GQKBAiyWyyhVOpONoZFmqKWCMEMxAAinSAFvCUVtJfaQi04rAQAPK0VgDh2kLBONTAdjd/Bk0x4KaYDOzzDiTDIBxtwfyZ55busPABYj9uxYbsEYh4JzH4b8RgsZc5N/CMSSWdKKo6w0AwDBUS8M0gYZUDCAptwAWnHORqn3ApLGsTpKlIdw%2BmabJSCSaI6AwxJIkI2gcMyFpujyFDanaMp7AqVoaPXOg6lKCiBm6ejiO43pvCaSjsmGIQPQmIYEykW1SHtJCnSkcQAA5YTg2FuB5ID5gbCMZB0sFcEIEhvSqeY7GLUtgmM74XX0PQ/RTINSFDcMo1jNzw3jK0pCTGTu3k9NM2zBzSHzKAYEQFBUHMstyEoKsLJCYBOBkTY%2BFbdtKC7Wde1oftj2HKLR3oSdpxXTAF3UZdZ1XWjN23JDd33Q9JiHU8vKQi8rxvDBJiQh8nxfPg6HfNgOC/YafwkbslG0FRFxQEC9DAgIIPWUhoNg6QEKQ4xaIsCB3GI7RUuwgT%2BhaX58NIgojtSgiCk4i7kNYwoeMYhJjuegp2IaM7cJAS6eg6d7XE%2BoHfvSf7fhEsSxstG1k1neSlJUtT5mAZBkC03TNn0/AiGIYzSFMqLq0snRNm0azFt0ezcxDMNI3c9zJJ859YV07huE2ABOHnrR52FNlhX5NhkeNZNTKQAqzHNAxC8KIELUmEtiysVZraZkDCMJrimTgeeubRFOuCAADUGE4WFrh5wZrnENT5BbVg22IDssqQnK8qkIcRzHEqZyQ%2BdFyqoO8DXMw6u7RqDyPH2T3oM9Z0669iBWW9er9R9n3j19hqYUbQiGwQRCm/8wzm9QFtdJbOtWqCYJieDEPTFjUIO9CQbcaxHrw%2B6Yl4q7khiXvmJqNi3viTDdpen7R744Gp9aej55hsZxM4eGpMRuTpAd9SnCEKYsf1nmI2NsELatiNbbxwzCYpkyzLJh/jplGyDDpwNhgQTBmCwEIa0vJszDGfa01oOYyG4ClIWcIea8ElutNMRhApywtAzFyzM3KSU2DvKWX90GSW0HgpB0sgr01IJuN2MQQDcCAA%3D%3D%3D)**)

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    set_al()
        movzx   eax, al            # The redundant sequence
        and     eax, 3
        cmp     eax, 3
        ja      .LBB0_2
        call    dummy()
.LBB0_2:
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

MSVC contained the same sequence.  GCC10.3 was similar but worse, materializing a boolean in a register and `test`ing it. (Both also in the same Godbolt link)

```
## GCC10.3
 ... set up RBP as a frame pointer
        movzx   eax, al            # The redundant sequence
        and     eax, 3
        cmp     eax, 3
        setbe   al
        test    al, al             # even worse than just jnbe
        je      .L2
        call    dummy()
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

---

**With the `char` coming from memory instead of a return value, GCC does optimize away the compare even in debug mode:**

```
int bar(unsigned char *p) {
    if ((*p & 3) <= 3U)
        dummy();
    return 0;
}
```

```
# GCC 10.3 -O0
bar(unsigned char*):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16                # space to spill the function arg
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        call    dummy()                # unconditional call
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

clang and MSVC do the test, both with asm like

```
#MSVC19.28 (VS16.9)  default options (debug mode)
     ...
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        and     eax, 3
        cmp     eax, 3
        ja      SHORT $LN2@bar
     ...
```